# Oracle sys_guid function returns weird syntax. How do I fix it?

Tags: oracle

I am running sys_guid() from dual on Oracle 12 and it's giving me this weird syntax:

SELECT SYS_GUID() FROM dual;
��[3e��S�� F

Every document I am looking at is showing this as a working syntax.
What is going on?

Comment: You mean, it returns *weir result*? That bunch of *garbage* characters? Which tool do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently
SELECT RAWTOHEX(SYS_GUID())FROM dual;
is the answer. Not sure why that's even necessary. But it works.